# IE8 is showing this error when i open the page "object dosen't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my-dropdown,#my-dropdown3').Select();
    });
</script>
```

When this executes I receive the error:

> object dosen't support this property or method

Comment: Well, the element does'nt support sSelect() ??? We have no idea what sSelect() is, so it's really not possible to answer why ?

Comment: sSelect? are you sure it is not a typo?

Comment: It should be .select() http://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: oh sorry, yeah but still the problem not with the sSelect .....
when i traced the error it referred to the "," 
so please provide help

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `sSelect()` and also the HTML you are using with this ...

Comment: it should be `.select()` and not `.Select()`!

Comment: -1 for lack of basic research - trivial search for "jQuery select" bring you to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/select/) - and JavaScript being case sensitive is pretty basic as well.

Comment: It's not a typo, `sSelect` sounds like a Javascript plugin, but the plugin seems not maintained (see http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/stylish-select-box) Here is a plugin which use the same name, not sure if it's the exactly the same plugin https://github.com/scottdarby/Stylish-Select/blob/master/jquery.stylish-select.js#L73. To correct the error, you have to retrieve the file and the line number of the error, and it seems like the error is not locate in the code you've provided so we can't help more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard -1 for lack of basic research, see this my answer and this http://bit.ly/IIAC5X (warning, Google display result for "select" and not "sSelect", you have to activate it)

Comment: @pomeh read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408982/ie8-is-showing-this-error-when-i-open-the-page-object-dosent-support-this-prop#comment13429560_10408982) by the OP. The first `s` was a typo, he posted his true code in a comment. If he really use such plugin, still -1 is in order for not including this vital information in the post.

Answer (score 0):

well correct your method as per the below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
   $('#my-dropdown,#my-dropdown3').select();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with your dropdown? Event `.select()` may not work on selectboxes because the documentation says

> The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text
>   selection inside it. http://api.jquery.com/select/

Bind an event `.change()` to select box `#my-dropdown` & `#my-dropdown3`?

```
    $('#my-dropdown,#my-dropdown3').change(function(){ 
       alert($(this).val());

    });
```